# Simpler way to create a matrix/list of indices?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, indices

I wonder what could be the easiest way to create a bi-dimensional array, that has for each row the indices to another multi-dimensional array.

For example, let's say I have a cube 4x4, the "indices matrix" would be the following:

```
np.concatenate([
    np.expand_dims(curr.ravel(),axis=0).T
    for curr
    in np.meshgrid(
        np.arange(4),
        np.arange(4),
        np.arange(4)
    )
],axis=1)
```

with the following result:

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 1],
      [0, 0, 2],
      [0, 0, 3],
      [1, 0, 0],
      [1, 0, 1],
      ...
      [2, 3, 2],
      [2, 3, 3],
      [3, 3, 0],
      [3, 3, 1],
      [3, 3, 2],
      [3, 3, 3]])
```

Besides the fact that it seems that the second column should be in place of the first, is there a more "numpythonic" way to create the same or similar matrix in a more compact way?

It would be nice if existed a function that just takes an arbitrary multi-dimensional array and returns it's index table.

Comment: The big question is: why do you want this? If you're planning to filter the index array and then index with it, for example, there are better ways to do that.

Comment: I will try to explain my goal with a few words as possible: I need to test some probability values that are stored in a 3-dimensional array. If they pass some test condition, then I will add them to a list of coordinates that will be visualized in a 3d scatter plot. Bigger picture: I am trying to visualize a decision boundary for a Linear Discriminant Analysis classifier (multi-class) running in 3 dimensions (features).

Comment: OK, the easiest way to do that isn't to get all the indices from `arr` and then filter it based the ones whose corresponding value in `arr` passes a test condition; instead, just apply the test to `arr` to get a boolean array, and then get the indices of the true values in that boolean array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`np.indices`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html):

```
>>> a = np.random.random((4,4,4))
>>> np.indices(a.shape).reshape((a.ndim, -1)).T
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 2],
       [0, 0, 3],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1],
[...]
       [3, 3, 2],
       [3, 3, 3]])
```

There are also other utilities like [`np.ndindex`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndindex.html), depending on your use case.  (FWIW I don't think getting the coordinates in the form you're looking for is going to be as helpful as you might think it is, but YMMV.)

Comment: Great. `np.ndindex` return generator, so if you want an output of array `np.indices` is the way to go. `np.indices(a.shape).reshape((a.ndim, -1)).T` is hundreds faster than `np.stack(np.ndindex(a.shape))`.

Answer (score 4):

I think

```
list(itertools.product(range(4),range(4),range(4)))
```

is more pythonic. .. (note you could use `numpy.array` instead of list if you were so inclined...)

Comment: This may be more pythonic, but it's less "numpythonic", and for huge arrays would probably be a bad idea… Still, the fact that it's readable to non-NumPy Python programmers is obviously an advantage for at least some use cases.

Answer (score 3):

> It would be nice if existed a function that just takes an arbitrary multi-dimensional array and returns it's index table.

If I understand your question, there is: [`indices`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html):

```
i = np.indices(a.shape)
```

This doesn't give you the results in the shape you wanted:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]])
>>> print(np.indices(a.shape))
[[[0 0]
  [1 1]
  [2 2]]

 [[0 1]
  [0 1]
  [0 1]]]
```

… but you can flatten it and transpose it:

```
[[0 0]
 [0 1]
 [1 0]
 [1 1]
 [2 0]
 [2 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do what I think you actually *want* to do. From your comment:

> I need to test some probability values that are stored in a 3-dimensional array. If they pass some test condition, then I will add them to a list of coordinates that will be visualized in a 3d scatter plot.

Let's say, for the same of simplicity, that the test is something simple, like "is positive". So, we just transform the array into a boolean array of "element is positive" for each element, which is just `arr > 0`, and then use [`nonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html#numpy.nonzero) to get the true indices of that boolean array:

```
>>> arr = np.array([[-1, 1], [2, -2], [-3, -3]])
>>> print(arr > 0)
[[False  True]
 [ True False]
 [False False]]
>>> print(np.nonzero(arr > 0))
(array([0, 1]), array([1, 0]))
```

Can't get much simpler than that.

Answer (score 0):

For those who came here to make a MATLAB array indexing, here is the solution:

```py
idx = np.indices(a.shape).reshape((a.ndim, -1)).T
idx = idx[idx[:,0].argsort()]
for i in range(1,len(a.shape),1):
    idx = idx[idx[:,i].argsort(kind='mergesort')]
```

Test:

```py
a = np.arange(24).reshape(3,2,4)
# array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
#         [ 4,  5,  6,  7]],

#        [[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
#         [12, 13, 14, 15]],

#        [[16, 17, 18, 19],
#         [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
idx = np.indices(a.shape).reshape((a.ndim, -1)).T
idx = idx[idx[:,0].argsort()]
for i in range(1,len(a.shape),1):
    idx = idx[idx[:,i].argsort(kind='mergesort')]

for i in idx:
    print(i, a[tuple(i)])
# [0 0 0] 0
# [1 0 0] 8
# [2 0 0] 16
# [0 1 0] 4
# [1 1 0] 12
# [2 1 0] 20
# [0 0 1] 1
# [1 0 1] 9
# [2 0 1] 17
# [0 1 1] 5
# [1 1 1] 13
# [2 1 1] 21
# [0 0 2] 2
# [1 0 2] 10
# [2 0 2] 18
# [0 1 2] 6
# [1 1 2] 14
# [2 1 2] 22
# [0 0 3] 3
# [1 0 3] 11
# [2 0 3] 19
# [0 1 3] 7
# [1 1 3] 15
# [2 1 3] 23
```