# Get all indices of an N-dimensional array as a list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, element, indices

Is there a way to get a list or array of all indices in an N-dimensional array in a fast and efficient way in Python?

For example, image we have the following array:

```
import numpy as np

test = np.zeros((4,4))

array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

I would like to get all element indices as follows:

```
indices = [ [0,0],[0,1],[0,2] ... [3,2],[3,3] ]
```

Comment: You could always use nested `for` loops

Comment: I was hoping for something quicker..that's not be trying to be rude I'm just trying to optimise some code and getting a list like above might be a good way to do it :)

Comment: Something in `itertools` should be able to generate all the combinations.

Comment: There's literally `numpy.indices`.

Comment: Thanks numpy.indices seemed to be the easiest!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`np.indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html) with a bit of reshaping:

```
np.indices(test.shape).reshape(2, -1).T
```

```
array([[0, 0],  
       [0, 1],  
       [0, 2],  
       [0, 3],  
       [1, 0],  
       [1, 1],  
       [1, 2],  
       [1, 3],  
       [2, 0],  
       [2, 1],  
       [2, 2],  
       [2, 3],  
       [3, 0],  
       [3, 1],  
       [3, 2],  
       [3, 3]])
```

Comment: Answer from the other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25026235/11671779) (duplicate hyperlink) is better in flexibility: `np.indices(a.shape).reshape((a.ndim, -1)).T`

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest making an array of `1` in the same shape as your `test` array using `np.ones_like`, then using `np.where`:

```
>>> np.stack(np.where(np.ones_like(test))).T
# Or np.dstack(np.where(np.ones_like(test)))
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 3],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 0],
       [3, 1],
       [3, 2],
       [3, 3]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> 
>>> [list(i) for i in product(range(4), range(4))]
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with using a list comprehension

```
test = np.zeros((4,4))
indices = [[i, j] for i in range(test.shape[0]) for j in range(test.shape[1])]
print (indices)

[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just enumerate should do:

```
test = [[0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.]]

indices = [[i, j] for i, row in enumerate(test) for j, col in enumerate(row)]
print(indices)

>>> [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [4, 0], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3]]
```

Comment: You might further want to convert the tuples into list